# Interpret image where the response is sent in the format "multipart response - MultiPartBoundary" API Surveillance cameras

Tags: php, rest, api, camera

I'm consuming a Surveillance Camera API, where it shows the live images, and the documentation says the answer is in multipart response format, where each JPEG image is preceded by a tag "- MultiPartBoundary" and I'm not sure how to interpret the return of those images in the browser.

```
<?php

$Cookie = (dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");


/*
* PRIMEIRA REQUISIÇÃO, RECEBE O COOKIE PARA O DOMINIO
*/
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
    CURLOPT_PORT           => '8000',
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://camerasquadion.ddns.net:8000/mjpegstream.cgi',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $Cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $Cookie,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 20000,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD        => "Admin:Quadion*1234",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_FILETIME       => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
        "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=MultiPartBoundary",
    ),
));


$responde  = curl_exec ($curl);

// Recupera o código HTTP retornado pela URL de destino
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);




/*
 * 2º Requisição, envio do cookie
 */
$ch = curl_init();

// Através da operação CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE estarei enviando meu COOKIE.
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => $Cookie,
    CURLOPT_URL             => 'http://camerasquadion.ddns.net:8000/mjpegstream.cgi?camera=108801',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
        "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=MultiPartBoundary",
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

// Recupera o código HTTP retornado pela URL de destino
$httpCode2 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

?>


<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?=base64_encode($response)?>">
```

Comment: What model camera. Can you give us a link to the API spec?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CURL part of your code works and obtains a valid response in $response.

The `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` setting will return not only the response body, but also the http headers as well. These need skipping in order to get the response body.

Then the response body is a series of images separated with the delimiter `"- MultiPartBoundary"`. You need to split the response body using that to get individual images.

```
list(,$responseBody) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);

$images = explode("- MultiPartBoundary", $responseBody);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode(trim($image)) .'">';
}
```